# Cardinality of Finite Group Subsets with Translation Property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let, $G$ be a finite group with $A\subset G$ ($A$ is not necessarily a group) such that for all $a\in A$, there does not exist some non-identity $x\in G$ with both $xa, x^{-1} a \in A$ (for the same $x$). How can we evaluate the maximal cardinality of $A$?

$A$ will of course depend on the structure of the group itself, not just the cardinality of it, so I do not expect some answer in terms of the size of the group but rather some method of obtaining $|A|$ through operations directly on $G$.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your statement for $S_n$, say $A=\{(1,2,3),(4,5)\}$ and $a=(1,2,3)$, then $x\ne 1$ and $xa\in A$ implies $xa=(4,5)$ so $x=(1,3,2)(4,5)$ and $x^{-1}a=(1,3,2)(4,5)\notin A$ that is no such $x$ exists and $|A|=2$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain right! Apologies

Comment: Sorry for misreading your query.

Comment: See, in case of cyclic groups your problem is essentially similar to [Golomb ruler problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler), which is pretty hard. The general case can't be simpler than that.